# Кнопка которая задает массив

Tags: javascript, html

Создал функцию которая создает таблицу и передал ей массив , далее создал 2 инпута и кнопку. Как же задать массив написав его значения инпута после которого нажав на кнопку это сработало.

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');


  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

var a = [["0", "0", "0",], ["0", ,"0", "0"]];

createTable(a);
```

```css
 body {
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-left:40%;
  
 
 }
 th,td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size:x-large;
  color:white;
 }
 tbody {
  background-color:blue;
 }
 input{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
 
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="col1">
<input type="text" class="col2">
<button class="btn">Go</button>
```

Comment: Код зачем удалили?

Comment: Вот поствил как надо

Comment: Ок, я ввел в инпуты 1 и 2, нажал на кнопку - что должно произойти?

Comment: вот я и хотел спросить нужно чтобы кнопка откликнулась и нарисовала мне массив

Comment: Какой массив должен быть нарисован?

Comment: ну например ввожу я в инпуты значение 4 и 5 таблица должна изменится и стать как 4 ряда и 5 столбцов как то так

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вам следует прописать у тега button атрибут onclick, а в нем указать ту функцию которую хотите вызвать по елику на кнопку.

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');


  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin-top:10%;
  margin-left:40%;
  
 
 }
 th,td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size:x-large;
  color:white;
 }
 tbody {
  background-color:blue;
 }
 input{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
 
 }
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" class="col1">
    <input type="text" class="col2">
    <button class="btn" onclick='createTable([["0", "0", "0",], ["0", ,"0", "0"]])'>Go</button> 
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Уважаемый, хватит постить низкокачественные ответы с нескольких аккаунтов плз.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму объясни что не так пожалуйста? Это я тебя как бывший js разработчик прошу)

Comment: @stack-it, а Вы потыкайте в сниппет и увидите) Ну и автору сообщение было адресовано, потому что человек подозрительно похожий на его твинка (точно сказать не могу пока Николас не пришел =)) опубликовал несколько штук низкокачественных ответов по js (этот еще относительно остальных - норм).

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму спасибо, код и правда не валидный. стал вводить двух-значные числа, не работает.

Comment: @stack-it, ну потому что таблица захардкожена, здесь просто рассказывается как рассказывается вешать обработчик на клик (причем плохим способом), а остальной код - из вопроса.

Comment: так там на кнопке нет обработчика чтоб работало , я и хочу спросить как сделать так чтоб заработало !!

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var rows = +document.querySelector(".col1").value;
    var cols = +document.querySelector(".col2").value;
    var row_arr = [];
    var col_arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var col_arr = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            col_arr.push(0); // содержимое ячейки
        }
        row_arr.push(col_arr);
    }
    createTable(row_arr);
});
```

Comment: все верно , но почему он не одну таблицу создает , а две

Comment: Он добавляет одну таблицу, просто ваша функция не удаляет все предыдущие таблицы, потому сколько раз жмакните - столько таблиц и получится (+ одна).

Comment: и как прописать эту функцию ?

Comment: Добавьте удаление старой таблицы в вашу функцию